# Aligning LVM's (vSphere)

Tags: vmware-vsphere, lvm, alignment

I would like to know if it is necessary to align LVM's in it?

I'm using VMware vSphere and as it is a best practise to align the disks (to 64 or 128 kb) I want to align every disk.

Thanks

EDIT: 
I'm using VMware vSphere and as it is a best practise to align the virtual disks (to 64 or 128 kb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create datastores in raw LUNs using the VI/VSClient in 3.5 or 4 it automatically aligns the disks. If you do it during installation or via the CLI you have do go out of your way. Hope this helps.

Comment: I mean the operating system disk, the virtual disk (vmdk).

Comment: In the ESX world the term LVM maps to LUNs and datastores within them, hence my answer. .vmdks are therefore inherently aligned themselves but obviously what you do with the guest file system is an entirely different matter.

Comment: I don't understand what your edit adds as you'd already stated these two things. As far as I am aware I have answered your question, if I have not then you need to be much clearer with your question phrasing.

Comment: The following forum topic from VMware gives more information: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/253209